# Amazon MWS submitFeed API Failure

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I am trying to add product on amazon using MWS submitFeed. When i make API call it returns following error

**SKU RGDSP*********, Missing Attributes product_type. SKU RGDSP********* does not match any ASIN. Creation of a new ASIN requires the following missing attributes: product_type. Feed ID: 0. For details, see http://sellercentral.amazon.in/gp/errorcode/200692370**

If i add ProductType to the script with some value it thorws **Invalid content was found starting with element 'ProductType'** error.

Below is my XML code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
    <AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
  <Header>
    <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
    <MerchantIdentifier>A28XP9******</MerchantIdentifier>
 </Header>
    <MessageType>Product</MessageType>
   <PurgeAndReplace>false</PurgeAndReplace>
 <Message>
<MessageID>1</MessageID>
<OperationType>Update</OperationType>
<Product>
  <SKU>SKU RGDSP*********</SKU>

  <ProductTaxCode>A_GEN_NOTAX</ProductTaxCode>
  <DescriptionData>
    <Title>Full Sleeves Kurta Pyjama Set For Men</Title>
    <Brand> Brand </Brand>
    <Description>Look your ethnic best when you adorn this kurta phyjama by RG Designers. Made from Cotton Fabric , it would lend you a glamorous look that is just perfect for any Occassion.  self textured  design kurta with White churidaar bottom.</Description>
    <BulletPoint>Made out of 100% Cotton fabric, Regular Fit, Full Sleeve, Chinese Collar Kurta For Men , Regular Fit white colored Pyjama with drawstring closure,</BulletPoint>
    <MSRP currency="INR">25.19</MSRP>
    <Manufacturer>Brand</Manufacturer>
    <ItemType>Ethnicwear</ItemType>
  </DescriptionData>

  </Product>
 </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

Kindly provide some help in fixing this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML is valid (except it has the final `</Message></AmazonEnvelope>` missing)

To add a product to Amazon which is not currently there, you will need to provide the `ProductType` structure. The following is a minimal valid XML containing one: only changes are after `</DescriptionData>`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
    <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>A28XP9******</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
    <MessageType>Product</MessageType>
    <PurgeAndReplace>false</PurgeAndReplace>
    <Message>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
        <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
        <Product>
            <SKU>SKU RGDSP*********</SKU>

            <ProductTaxCode>A_GEN_NOTAX</ProductTaxCode>
            <DescriptionData>
                <Title>Full Sleeves Kurta Pyjama Set For Men</Title>
                <Brand> Brand </Brand>
                <Description>Look your ethnic best when you adorn this kurta phyjama by RG Designers. Made from Cotton Fabric , it would lend you a glamorous look that is just perfect for any Occassion.  self textured  design kurta with White churidaar bottom.</Description>
                <BulletPoint>Made out of 100% Cotton fabric, Regular Fit, Full Sleeve, Chinese Collar Kurta For Men , Regular Fit white colored Pyjama with drawstring closure,</BulletPoint>
                <MSRP currency="INR">25.19</MSRP>
                <Manufacturer>Brand</Manufacturer>
                <ItemType>Ethnicwear</ItemType>

            </DescriptionData>
            <ProductData>
                <Clothing>
                    <ClassificationData>
                        <ClothingType>Sleepwear</ClothingType>
                        <Department>x</Department>
                        <StyleKeywords>x</StyleKeywords>
                    </ClassificationData>
                </Clothing>
            </ProductData>
        </Product>
    </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

Comment: thanks @hazzit i was able to fix that part by adding productData. But i am still getting "Some attributes are missing for SKU: [RGDSP10613_PEACH-36].For more details, see http://sellercentral.amazon.in/gp/errorcode/8058" error.

I did compare my values with the template, but still getting that error.